# How do I interpolate a variable from one data frame to another matching time in R

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I have data from two separate temperature data loggers. They both have *Time* and *Celsius* as columns. Below is code that will recreate a subset of 15 values from the two data loggers. They are typically off by a few seconds.

```
Time <- as.POSIXct(c("2014-07-16 13:09:38", "2014-07-16 13:09:48", "2014-07-16 13:09:58", "2014-07-16 13:10:08", "2014-07-16 13:10:18", "2014-07-16 13:10:28", "2014-07-16 13:10:38", "2014-07-16 13:10:48", "2014-07-16 13:10:58", "2014-07-16 13:11:08", "2014-07-16 13:11:18", "2014-07-16 13:11:28", "2014-07-16 13:11:38", "2014-07-16 13:11:48", "2014-07-16 13:11:58"))
Celsius <- c(27.5, 27.5, 27.5, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28.5, 28.5, 28.5, 28.5, 28.5, 29, 29)
df1 <- data.frame(Time,Celsius)
Time <-  as.POSIXct(c("2014-07-16 13:09:39", "2014-07-16 13:09:49", "2014-07-16 13:09:59", "2014-07-16 13:10:09", "2014-07-16 13:10:19", "2014-07-16 13:10:29", "2014-07-16 13:10:39", "2014-07-16 13:10:49", "2014-07-16 13:10:59", "2014-07-16 13:11:09", "2014-07-16 13:11:19", "2014-07-16 13:11:29", "2014-07-16 13:11:39", "2014-07-16 13:11:49", "2014-07-16 13:11:59"))
Celsius <- c(26.6666666666667, 26.6666666666667, 26.6666666666667, 27.2222222222222, 27.2222222222222, 27.2222222222222, 27.2222222222222, 27.7777777777778, 27.7777777777778, 27.7777777777778, 27.7777777777778, 27.7777777777778, 28.3333333333333, 28.3333333333333, 28.3333333333333)
df2 <- data.frame(Time,Celsius)
```

**How do I interpolate (linear) the *Celsius* on the second data frame matching to the times in the first data frame?** I am ok with losing a few rows at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `approxfun` will come in handy here. First of all, you want to make sure your temperature measurements are numeric. In your sample they seem to be factors for some reason, so you can change them with

```
df1$Celsius<-as.numeric(as.character(df1$Celsius))
df2$Celsius<-as.numeric(as.character(df2$Celsius))
```

Now we can use the `approxfun` on `df2` to define a translation function from the date/time to the temp.

```
tx<-approxfun(df2$Time, df2$Celsius)
```

and then use that function on the `df1$Time` to get a prediction of the `df2` temperature at each of the `df1` times

```
tx(df1$Time)
```

Comment: I edited the question to have the correct numeric values like you suggested. Thanks for the answer.